# Spring JPA find distinct with order by

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm gonna make select which looks like:

```
findDistinctByPatientOrderByVisits_DateDesc(patient: Patient, page: Pageable): Page<Treatment>
```

Treatment is a table that contains patient and their visits which can be more to single treatment.
I need to do distinct cause with only OrderBy I'm getting duplicated treatments.

This entities has fields:

```
@Entity
class Treatment(
    @OneToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), mappedBy = "Instance")
    var visits: MutableList<Visit> = mutableListOf()
    @ManyToOne
    val patient: Patient
)
@Entity
class Visit(
    var date: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.MAX,

)
```

But I'm getting error:

> SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Answer (score 0):

That error means that you are trying to order by a field that is not present in the SELECT section of the query. So it can't order by date.

I think your problem resides into FetchType that should be LAZY by default, so it does not retrieve date var and it can't order by that value.

You could try to change your FetchType to EAGER or you could write a query like this

@Query(value = "SELECT t, v FROM Treatment t JOIN t.visits v ORDER BY v.date")

Otherwise you could use criteria api